# images are not loading inside WEB-INF folder?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have `some.jsp` in WEB-INF folder. inside jsp i have below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/form.js"></script>
```

inside `form.js` i have below code:

```
$('#theform #formProgress').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Saving&hellip;');
```

`ajax-loader.gif` is in `webapp/public/images` folder .

But the image is not loading. Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: should i mention public also? Thanks!

Comment: Your JS files do, why wouldn't your images?

Answer (score 1):

Your own text answers the question: you're using the wrong file path:

```
$('#theform #formProgress').html('<img src="/public/images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Saving&hellip;');
```

If the image is in `/public/images`, why try loading it from `/images`?

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `form.js`? if it is inside the `public/js` directory and images are inside `public/images` then you just need to write:

```
$('#theform #formProgress').html('<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Saving&hellip;');
```